# Lapplying a function over two lists of dataframes in R

Tags: r

I've got two lists of dataframes: `list_A` and `list_B`. I want to take in consecutive dataframes from `list_A` and `list_B` and apply a custom function to them (`my_function`).

This works as desired:

```
my_function(list_A[[1]], list_B[[1]])
my_function(list_A[[2]], list_b[[2]])
...
```

However, I don't know how to do with `lapply` so that I don't have to type in the number each time (I have several hundred elements). Also, I would like the results to be written to one list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we could use `Map` from `base R` to apply the function on the corresponding elements of both the `list`s

```
out <- Map(my_function, list_A, list_B)
```

---

`lapply` can also be used, if we loop over the sequence of one of the `list`

```
out <- lapply(seq_along(list_A), function(i) 
     my_function(list_A[[i]], list_B[[i]]))
```

which is similar to using a `for` loop

```
out <- vector('list', length(list_A))
for(i in seq_along(list_A)) out[[i]] <- my_function(list_A[[i]], list_B[[i]])
```

Answer (score 3):

`mapply` would do what you need, for example:

```
myfunction <- sum
mapply(myfunction, list(1, 2, 3), list(10,20,30))
# [1] 11 22 33
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can vectorize `my_function` via `Vectorize`, e.g.,

```
Vectorize(my_function)(list_A,list_B)
```