# How to merge separate lapply and enable pivot_long column reading

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse, lapply

I am performing the same operation through separated list of dataset

```
    
        library(glue)
    
    x1 = c('mpg', 'cyl') 
    x2 = c('Month', 'Ozone') 
    
    list_x = list(x1, x2)
      
    rm(list = ls())
    mtcars
    data1 = mtcars
    colnames = colnames(data1)
    colnames(data1) <- lapply(seq_along(mtcars), \(x) paste0(colnames(mtcars)[x], x))
    colnames(data1) = lapply(colnames(mtcars), \(x) glue(x, '{1}'))
    
    data_c = cbind(mtcars, data1)
    
    data2 = airquality
    colnames = colnames(airquality)
    colnames(data2) <- lapply(seq_along(airquality), \(x) paste0(colnames(airquality)[x], x))
    colnames(data2) = lapply(colnames(airquality), \(x) glue(x, '{1}'))
    
    data_cc = cbind(airquality, data2)
    
    list_combined = list(list(data_c, data_c), list(data_cc, data_cc))
    
    dput(head(list_combined, 10))
    
    
    flatten(lapply(seq(1:2), function(y)
      lapply(seq(1:2), function(j) {    
        cols = colnames(list_combined[[y]][[j]])
        if (str_detect(cols, list_x[[y]][j]) == T) {
          list_combined[[y]][[j]] %>% 
            select(starts_with(list_x[[y]][j]))
        }})))

     rm(list = ls())
```

The final output that I would like to achieve is to cycling select the string within the vector list, so that to create a new list with the first list containing just the first element of the list_x and the second list of the first list containig the second element of the list_x object and the same is with second list and elements in the second list of list_x.

```
    final_list[[1]][[1]]
    #selected columns 
    mpg, mpg1
    
    
    final_list[[1]][[2]]
    #selected columns 
    cyl, cyl1
    
    final_list[[2]][[1]]
    #selected columns 
    Month, Month1
    
    final_list[[2]][[2]]
    #selected columns 
    Ozone, Ozone1
```

I have tried something like this but unfortunately I cannot get the wanted output.

But  I am getting the following error:

```
Error in if (str_detect(cols, list_x[[y]][j]) == T) { :
the condition has length > 1
```

Would you recommend a different approach? I would the most general code to do this that might fit some diffrent data too. Thanks

Comment: hi 12666727b9. Can you share `dput(datalist1)` please? Thanks!

Comment: Also your code is missing a closing curly bracket

Comment: hello, but in any case the point here is that when I try to move the function in a loop in such a way to replace  index in square brackets of datalist1[[i]], this return an error. My data are too huge to be used here. So maybe, if it happened to yoou something similar maybe you could know how  to cope with it

Comment: Use dput(head()) then

Comment: In my experience, questions with sample data get answered in a few hours, ones without it are rarely answered. Up to you

Comment: ok. But unfortunately that object is big since it is a list of lists and it is quite unlikely to provide a reprex for it

Comment: I have tried to create some examples

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255355/discussion-between-mark-and-12666727b9).

Comment: new error: `Error in `pivot_longer()`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
ℹ Locations 16, 17, and 18 don't exist.`

Comment: @Mark I have tried to summarize with a new example

Comment: Its impossible to provide a proper solution because what you are trying to achieve is unclear, and the code you provided is disjointed, the variables you use are undefined.   But the error you have is straight forward enough,   str_detect is returning a vector with more than one element, but the conditional if allows only one.  Depending on what you want you could do `if (any(str_detect(cols, list_x[[y]][j])) == T)`

Comment: @MarkHamlin the `==T` is redundant

Comment: @12666727b9 your question still is extremely confusing and hard to understand. Make a MUCH smaller example, and then create the desired output by hand. Then add that to your question

Comment: Note: you added that huge `list(list(structure(list(mpg = etc...` list to your question, but don't even name it. I don't really know what to make of your question, it seems quite odd

Comment: @Mark Ihavee tried to add more detials. Hope this could help.

Comment: please refrain from adding  `rm(list = ls())` to your example. if people copy and paste your code and run it will remove all of their objects in their environment

Comment: I added that code

Comment: @Mark Hamlin it works pretty nice the solution that you proposed, but I would need to how to set the `else statement` since with me returns `no loop for break/next, jumping to top level`

Comment: @MarkHamlin I think they were wanting to tag you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65778918/17918739)):

Map+ purrr::map2

```
solution1 <- Map(\(list1,list2) purrr::map2(list1, list2, \(x,y) select(x,starts_with(y))),list_combined,list_x)

str(solution1)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  .. ..$ mpg1: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  .. ..$ cyl1: num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    153 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Month : int [1:153] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  .. ..$ Month1: int [1:153] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    153 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Ozone : int [1:153] 41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
  .. ..$ Ozone1: int [1:153] 41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
```

lapply+purrr::map2

```
solution2 <- lapply(seq_along(list_combined), \(i)
  purrr::map2(list_combined[[i]], list_x[[i]], \(x,y) select(x,starts_with(y))))

str(solution2)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  .. ..$ mpg1: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  .. ..$ cyl1: num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    153 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Month : int [1:153] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  .. ..$ Month1: int [1:153] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    153 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Ozone : int [1:153] 41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
  .. ..$ Ozone1: int [1:153] 41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
```

Base R solution:

```
Map(\(list1,list2) Map(\(x,y) x[,startsWith(names(x),y)],list1, list2),list_combined,list_x)
```

To select multiple columns:

```
x1 = c(list('mpg'), list('cyl')) 
x2 = c(list('Month'), list(c('Ozone',"Wind") ))

list_x = list(x1, x2)

solution2_multiple_columns <- lapply(seq_along(list_combined), function(i)
  purrr::map2(list_combined[[i]], list_x[[i]], \(x,y) select(x,starts_with(y))))

str(solution2_multiple_columns)

List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  .. ..$ mpg1: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  .. ..$ cyl1: num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    153 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Month : int [1:153] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  .. ..$ Month1: int [1:153] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    153 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ Ozone : int [1:153] 41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
  .. ..$ Ozone1: int [1:153] 41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
  .. ..$ Wind  : num [1:153] 7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
  .. ..$ Wind1 : num [1:153] 7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks. I will test it and I will let you know, if they work. :)

Comment: Really. Thank you. Let's supposed that alternatively for each sublist of main list I would like to assign a different columns set. Which could be the most general code to use? I have tried so far with the last one, but unfortunately I cannot manage to fit it properly to my case.

Comment: It seems like solution 2 (lapply+purrr::map2) works nicely. See update.

Comment: great. Thanks. Can I just ask if I want to convert as a pivot format, if is sufficient to enteer the columns index with a pivot_longer function after the pipe %>% operator?